# Jolt Convert string attribut to array only if it match to a condition

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I have this input

```
[
  {
    "attributeKey": "foo",
    "stringValue": "fooValue",
  },
  {
    "attributeKey": "bar",
    "stringValue": "barValue1¤barValue2",
  }
]
```

And I want to transform it to this output

```
{ 
  "foo" : "fooValue",
  "bar" : ["barValue1", "barValue2"]
}
```

**The rules are :**

- Whenever we found an element in the input array that have an attribute `stringValue` containing **¤** character we should split/transform it to an array of strings.
- The type of the value result in the output is very important : for `attributeKey` that have a `stringValue` containing **¤** separator the result should be an array of strings (splitted values), otherwise the result should be a string.

**PLEASE NOT THAT THE VALUES OF THE attributeKey ARE NOT KNOWN BEFOREHAND, THEY MAY CHANGE ANYTIME!**

I have tried with this spec :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(1,[&].stringValue)": {
          "*": {
            "$": "@(3,attributeKey)"
          },
          "*\\¤*": {
            "$": "@(3,attributeKey)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But it gives me only this :

```
{
  "foo" : "fooValue",
  "bar" : "barValue1¤barValue2"
}
```

I tied many attempts to split the result but without succeeding !

---

**UPDATE**
@barbaros solution, adding :

```
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "bar": "=split('¤', @(1,&))"
  }
}
```

gives the desired result ***only if we know the values of `attributeKey` before hands***, for example in my case I could receive a json containing different values :

```
[
  {
    "attributeKey": "baz",
    "stringValue": "bazValue1¤bazValue2",
  },
]
```

In this case the provided solution will not work, since values of attributeKey changes every time ! So we should be able to perform the split/transformation no matter the value of `attributeKey` in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following **modify-overwrite-beta** spec containing **split** function to the current **shift** spec

```json
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "bar": "=split('¤', @(1,&))"
  }
}
```

[image]

**Edit :**

Depending on your need, you can make **modify-overwrite-beta** spec. the first step, and walk through the objects of the array, and then shorten the shift spec as below

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "stringValue": "=split('¤', @(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(2,[&].stringValue)": {
          "*": "@(2,attributeKey)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: the value of attributeKey could change anytime and I don't have a fixed values, and also if `stringValue` doesn't contains `¤` (the separator) the output should not be an array but a simple string

Comment: well, what can be those seperator values @AbdelghaniRoussi ? Can you express that along with the next explanation( *the output should not be an array but a simple string* )  by editing the question...?

Comment: Yes of course, I've updated the question